# Windows Firewall protected network connections blocked by local group policy

Tags: group-policy, windows-firewall

I have a couple of Windows 2008R2 servers running as stand-alones (that is, not connected to a Domain). 
In Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, I'm trying to **unprotect** a local network connection because the firewall is interfering with my NetVault backups. When I open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security and click on the Windows Firewall Properties link I see this: 
[Windows Firewall Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEQBG.png)
Note the information banner at the top.

When I click Customize next to the Protected network connections label, I see this:
[Protected Network Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5PN9.png)
Again, note the banner at the top.

Neither of the checkboxes are active.

Obviously, local Group Policy (LGP) has taken over. 
Google doesn't know which of the LGP settings covers this, so I'm asking ServerFault for some help. Any ideas?

When I opened LGP and navigated to Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Network Connections\Windows Firewall\Standard Profile\Windows Firewall: Protect all network connections, it was Disabled!

Setting this to Enabled or Not Configured did not change anything (still can't change the Firewall setting), even with rebooting after each change.

I've run rsop.msc to get a list of the local group policy changes; none seem obvious for either of these settings.

Google is unclear what LGP setting controls the "some settings are controlled by Group Policy", so I'm asking for help with this setting as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were these servers ever joined to an AD domain?

Comment: There isn't a specific setting for "some settings are controlled by Group Policy". It would be any firewall setting if managed through the policy editor. `Protect all network connections` only provides a mechanism to ensure that Windows can be turned off. It has nothing to do with the Protected Network Connections. The policy editor firewall console also does not know anything about specific connections. Simplest fix would be to use the policy editor firewall console to disable the firewall for the network profile, or create rules to allow the application to work through the firewall.

Comment: @joeqwerty Nope, these were never joined to a domain.

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks for the info, Greg. The "Protect all network connections" was a red herring, and should be dropped from this thread (I may ask another question in more detail about that).